# Como pegar valores de td individual de tabela dinâmica sem clicar na linha

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho um `button` que envia o formulário, e dentro do formulário têm os campos respectivos, dentro do fomulário tem uma tabela que traz dinanmicamente os dados do banco que está permite edição dos valores de cada linha:
[image: tabela]

```js
    $("#update-baixa").click(function () {

        var item = $("[data-idparcela]").closest("tr").children('td:eq(1)');

        console.log(item.val());

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tablemdlreceita" class="table table-sm table-bordered table-responsive">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Documento</th>
            <th>Vlr Programado</th>
            <th>Dt Vencto</th>
            <th colspan="2" class="text-center">Ações</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody><tr>
            <td>FR212</td>
            <td>220.00</td>
            <td>30/01/2019</td>
            <td align="center">
                <a class="omdleditreceita" data-idparcela="3">Editar</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>FR212</td>
            <td>400.00</td>
            <td>25/01/2019</td>
            <td align="center">
                <a class="omdleditreceita" data-idparcela="4">Editar</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody><tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="9" align="center">
                <div class="pagination-wrap">
                    <ul class="pagination"><li><a href="/add-data.php?page_no=1" style="color:red;">1</a></li></ul>                                                
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

                        <button type="button" id="update-baixa" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="fas fa-plus"></span>Salvar</button>
```

Só que não está pegando o valor individual de cada td da coluna |Vlr Programado|

Comment: Altere:
closest para parents e val() para text().

Comment: Certo ele pegou, porém ele está pegando o valor da linha dois apenas.
Preciso que ele pegue o valor da linha 1 para que eu possa armazenar em uma váriavel e depois da linha dois e fazer o mesmo.

Comment: Ele está pegando apenas uma linha pois foi definido o `td:eq(1)`. Remova o `eq` e trate o retorno como um *array*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se do jeito que está implementado seu código, terá um desempenho bom, mas se quiser pode pegar os valores de cada `td` apenas setando sua posição a partir dos atributos **data**.

```js
$("#update-baixa").click(function() {

  var tam = $("[data-idparcela]").length;

  for (var i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
    for(var j = 1; j<tam; j++) {
      var item = $("[data-idparcela]:eq("+i+")").parents("tr").children("td:eq("+j+")");

      console.log(item.text());

     }
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tablemdlreceita" class="table table-sm table-bordered table-responsive">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Documento</th>
      <th>Vlr Programado</th>
      <th>Dt Vencto</th>
      <th colspan="2" class="text-center">Ações</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>FR212</td>
      <td>220.00</td>
      <td>30/01/2019</td>
      <td align="center">
        <a class="omdleditreceita" data-idparcela="3">Editar</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>FR212</td>
      <td>400.00</td>
      <td>25/01/2019</td>
      <td align="center">
        <a class="omdleditreceita" data-idparcela="4">Editar</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="9" align="center">
        <div class="pagination-wrap">
          <ul class="pagination">
            <li><a href="/add-data.php?page_no=1" style="color:red;">1</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button type="button" id="update-baixa" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="fas fa-plus"></span>Salvar</button>
```

Comment: Qual seria uma forma para que pudesse ter um melhor desempenho?
eu ainda não tinha utilizado esses seletores do JS.

Comment: É que eu não sei qual será o tamanho da tabela, pois como você será dinâmica, desta maneira o código está percorrendo muitas vezes o DOM, podendo ter algum problema de performance, dependendo de como disse, do tamanho da tabela.

Comment: Eu também não sei ao certo o tamanho, é dinâmico.
mais desse jeito deu certo, para fazer um for e pegar todos os valores onde `eq[i]` porque por exemplo se eu tiver mais de duas linhas ele já pegue tudo, tem como dessa forma que está meu código?

Comment: Editei a resposta utilizando um **for**.

Comment: Valeu, muito obrigado, era isso mesmo que preciso.